# Spark sql version of the same query does not work whereas the normal sql query does

Tags: python, mysql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The normal sql query :

```
    SELECT DISTINCT(county_geoid), state_geoid, sum(PredResponse), sum(prop_count) FROM table_a GROUP BY county_geoid;
```

Gives me an output. However the spark sql version of this same query used in pyspark is giving me an error. How to resolve this issue?

```
    result_county_performance_alpha = spark.sql("SELECT distinct(county_geoid), sum(PredResponse), sum(prop_count), state_geoid FROM table_a group by county_geoid")
```

This gives an error :

```
AnalysisException: u"expression 'tract_alpha.`state_geoid`' is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function. Add to group by or wrap in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.;
```

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "normal" query should not work anywhere.  The correct way to write the query is:

```
SELECT county_geoid, state_geoid, sum(PredResponse), sum(prop_count)
FROM table_a
GROUP BY county_geoid, state_geoid;
```

This should work on any database (where the columns and tables are defined and of the right types).

Your version has `state_geoid` in the `SELECT`, but it is not being aggregated.  That is not correct SQL.  It might happen to work in MySQL, but that is due to a (mis)feature in the database (that is *finally* being fixed).

Also, you almost never want to use `SELECT DISTINCT` with `GROUP BY`.  And, the parentheses after the `DISTINCT` make no difference.  The construct is `SELECT DISTINCT`.  `DISTINCT` is not a function.

Comment: which feature ? could you explain more on why it works only in mysql?

Comment: I understood the distinct use is a mistake, but when using group by with state_geoid and without in mysql, the answer varies.